# How can i make table layout width equivalent to container width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `table layou`t inside my `container-fluid`. How can i make table layout width equivalent to container width.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="table-layout">
        <div class="table-cell fixed-width-100">
            <p>fixed width div</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <p>fluid width div</p>    
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell fixed-width-100">
            <p>fixed width div</p>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.table-layout {
 display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.table-layout .table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}

.fixed-width-100 {
    width:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

How can i make table layout width equivalent to container width. There is some padding and margin on both the sides. Attached is screen-shot.

[image]

Comment: Why not try removing the `width: 100%` from `.table-layout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue comes from padding or margin on the `<body>` tag. Add :

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/twQL6/)

Comment: How can i make the two left and right column of parent height? The cells height must be of parent.

Comment: @Shane in the fiddle I posted, the left and right columns are the same height as their parent, do you mean you want them to be as heigh as the window?

Comment: yes height as the window with overscroll... enabled

Comment: Thanks... but why is the overflow-y not visible?

Comment: Hmmmm.... If you're using Bootstrap, there's a css reset in the bootstrap.css that would already eliminate the html/body margins/padding.  However, containers always have 15px of padding left/right.  A row has -15px margin left/right.  That's why you always add a row to a container.

Comment: @Shane I showed you haow to get the scrollable table-cell on the left column, you just have to apply the same technique on the right one.

Comment: Its strange here.... i am not sure why is there a scroll-bar not scrolling. http://jsfiddle.net/twQL6/10/embedded/result/